# how to use req.body as a function argument - NEXT.js api

Tags: node.js, next.js

i want to pass a HTTP POST request body as a function argument.
here's my code

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).send({ message: "GET not allowed" });
    return;
  }
  const data = req.body;

  try {
    const { hash, uri } = await upload(data); // use req.body {key:value} as func arg
    res.status(200).json({ id: hash, uri: uri });
  } catch (err) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ msg: "upload failed", error: err.message });
  }
}
```

i get an error, `error: "Unexpected input: cannot convert \"object\" into ImportCandidate"`

this works for a normal "string"

Comment: Probably that's the problem: you're passing an object to a function that probably expects a string or is trying to destructure the argument you provide (in this case req.body) but fails to find the properties it is looking for. What type of argument does the `upload` function expects?

Comment: Any.
But for my use case, i will be passing a JSON object as the request body.

Comment: @JuanDeLasNieves consider an object as argument

Answer (score 1):

Got it working...
I forgot that I need to serialise the object again before uploading it.

`const data = JSON.stringify(req.body);`

Solves it. Thanks

Comment: Great, I was thinking about parsing and it was the opposite. Glad you figured it out